# \r\n in scala parser for Windows/Unix

Tags: regex, windows, scala, unix, encode

I've got scala regex test which parse string with multiple lines. It looks like following:

```
val s = "This is one line\r\n" +
        "The second line\r\n" +
        "third"
```

Scala test with **"\r\n"** is working for Windows, but for Unix i should keep just **"\n"**. Is it common solution to work on both systems?

Answer (score 0):

You could test for `\r?\n` instead of `\r\n`. That way the carriage return is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing common line separator for all systems is the option i prefer:

```
val newLine = sys.props("line.separator")
```